# SpecFlow test with Gherkin table also trying column name in tests

Tags: c#, specflow

I have this Specflow Feature:

```
Given I have CoolData with <a> , <b> , <c> and <d>: 
| a                | b        | c         | d            |
| cool data        |          | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.4      |           | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.3      | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.3      | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
```

For which I have this method:

```
[Given(@"Given I have CoolData with (.*) , (.*) , (.*) and (.*) :")]
    public void GivenIhaveCoolDatawithAnd(string p0, string p1, string p2, string p3, Table table)
    {
        var cool = new CoolData
        {
            a= p0,
            b= decimal.Parse(p1),
            c= decimal.Parse(p2),
            d= p3,
        };
    }
```

My problem: when I run this test, `p0`, `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are mapped to strings that literally say `"<a>"`, `"<b>"`, `"<c>"` and `"<d>"`, instead of the values in the tables. What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to repeat the unit test for each row in this table.

Comment: Looks like you just need to skip first row of data which contain the column headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how gherkin works. What you have done is conflate two concepts, the table and scenario examples. See [the documentation for cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference) and look at the difference between data tables and scenario outlines

I believe you don't want a table in this instance and so you should use a scenario outline with examples, like this:

```
Scenario Outline: some title
    Given I have CoolData with <a> , <b> , <c> and <d>

Examples:
| a                | b        | c         | d            |
| cool data        |          | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.4      |           | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.3      | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
| cool data        | 1.3      | 1.3       | Cool notes   |
```

This will cause 4 tests to be generated each one running one line of data from the example

you will also need to adjust your step method to not expect a table now (as the table is now a set of examples)

```
[Given(@"Given I have CoolData with (.*) , (.*) , (.*) and (.*)")]
    public void GivenIhaveCoolDatawithAnd(string p0, string p1, string p2, string p3)
    {
        var cool = new CoolData
        {
            a= p0,
            b= decimal.Parse(p1),
            c= decimal.Parse(p2),
            d= p3,
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that! However, when I use the `Examples:` keyword in the way you describe, I get an error in Visual Studio's Error List: `Custom tool error: (14:2): expected: #EOF, #TableRow, #DocStringSeparator, #StepLine, #TagLine, #ScenarioLine, #ScenarioOutlineLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Examples:' `

Comment: you probably need a capital 'O' in `Scenario Outline`

Comment: Doh! Thanks for setting me straight.